# IF STATEMENT for check if columns in table was filled

Tags: mysql

I need a query where if a column from a row was filled, return her, else return another column value in the same table.
This code will insert like a subquery, so, I need that return just only value.
**
Data Base Exemple**

| ID | Name | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maria | Nunes |
| 2 | *Null* | Torres |

**Expected query**

SELECT *,

(*new subquery FROM TableName) AS Name,

FROM
Table2.

**Expected response**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Maria |
| 2 | Torres |

Actually, I get the two values from columns and mount an object with "if statement" separately to check if value is difference of "null"

Comment: Are you saying there are two tables?  If so please show sample data from both and how they combine to produce your results.  If not, sounds like you just want `select ID, coalesce(Name, LastName) as Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
  `ID`,
  COALESCE(`Name`, `LastName`) AS `Name`
FROM 
  `Table2`
```

Comment: You answer is short and functional. Thanks. Help me so much.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement.

```
SELECT Name, LastName, (case when (Name is null)
THEN
    LastName
ELSE
    Name
END
)
as data from Table2;
```